# Documentation icon not displaying properly on Jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design, stack-overflow-jobs

When going to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab the documentation icon look like this:

[image: Weird documentation icons.]

Fairly sure this isn't intended.

Comment: The badge icons are OK. But that weird thing is supposed to be the documentation icon.

Comment: I can't repro; I *suspect* it might be a CDN / deployment issue (breaking a sprite); is there any chance you could dump your local cache and retry? if this fixes it, then we can check/fix what went wrong in the deploy; if it doesn't fix it, we can dig deeper into what is happening

Comment: The problem is the `background-size: 200px 200px;` property which causes the sprite to scale down and thus the background position is no longer correct.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yup that did the trick.

Comment: @TreviAwater k, in that case I'm going to mark this as closed and we can chase down the other stuff internally